# Роза ветров может лежать в основе маршрута?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

> А пока я худо-бедно изобразила некое подобие контурной карты –
>   составила маршрут, в основе которого лежала роза ветров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Роза ветров может графически *изображаться* (быть нанесённой) в исходной точке одного или нескольких маршрутов, но не "лежать в основе маршрута": это означало бы *произвольность направления*. Это примерно то же, что сказать "в основу маршрута был положен компас".

Comment: С компасом - убедил, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

**В принципе всё верно:** картографическая точность выражений здесь необязательна, так как смысл переносный.

Вот только **от терминологии** тогда надо бы держаться подальше, в частности, хотелось бы убрать местоимение ***который,*** характерное для научно-книжной речи.

А если так:

***А пока я худо-бедно изобразила некое подобие контурной карты – нарисовала розу ветров и по ней составила маршрут.***

Comment: Sharon, не пойму, зачем вы запятую поставили после *в частности?*

Comment: Это вводное слово. Или нет?

Comment: Это присоединительная конструкция: http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=27. Вроде и в этом случае запятая нужна только в конце оборота. Так же с "например" в случае существительных-примеров.

Comment: Вводное слово присоединяется к обороту при обособлении его запятой, а здесь БСП. Розенталь в этом случае позволяет  на границе предложений обособлять вводное слово, например: Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Comment: Но: *Тучи надвигаются, значит будет дождь.* http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133

Comment: Всё-таки, похоже, вы меня убедили, что это не присоединительный оборот у вас. Спасибо, теперь лучше уяснил для себя этот момент. Насколько я понял, ситуация такая же, как с "например".

Comment: В  сложных предложениях относительно вводных слов у нас двоевластие, но я больше уважаю Розенталя, поэтому вводные слова обособляю. И еще я хочу спросить вас по текущему вопросу: как вы думаете, здесь "контурные карты" имеют какой смысл? Может быть, их в кавычки заключить, так как на самом деле  это просто  рисунок с контурами?

Comment: Про тучи это тоже Розенталь. ;) Не знаю, мне всё-таки кажется, что тут сравнение с настоящей контурной картой. То есть у неё, может, и рисунок с контурами, но подобен он ("подобие") нормальной контурной карте. А вообще, если честно, то я не понял, как роза ветров могла повлиять на маршрут. Старались идти больше по ветру, что ли (с определённой вероятностью)?

Comment: Скорее всего, в тех краях ветер в определенные периоды бывает очень сильным и может серьезно осложнить жизнь. Это приходится учитывать, когда планируешь путешествие, причем не только на воздушном шаре. А по вашей ссылке открывается Лопатин, да я и так знаю его грамматические "открытия": Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.). Вот кому в этих двух предложениях непонятно, к какой части относится вводное слово? Мне бы хотелось на него посмотреть.

Comment: *А по вашей ссылке открывается Лопатин...* Точно! Всё перепутал, кто из них кто. Я воспринимал, что запятую Лопатин рекомендует ставить не из-за непонятности, а просто потому что так лучше читается. На самом деле не так?

Comment: Лопатин и не задумывался никогда, как лучше читается, это не его поход.  Лопатин: § 94. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127 Вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Если предполагается путешествие на воздушном шаре, то почему бы и нет? Для других же видов путешествий маршрут на основе розы ветров выглядит странновато. Должна быть какая-то логическая связь, а здесь её совершенно не наблюдается.